# How to get rid of circle inside rectangle when switching between objects

Tags: java, swing

I have a combobox in which I can choose to draw either a rectangle, a circle or by freehand.
If I choose to draw a circle it draws it perfectly. If I then switch to draw a rectangle it draws a circle inside the rectangle. The same happens if I first choose to draw a rectangle and then a circle. (See Picture below)

My questions are:

1. How can I switch between drawing a circle and a rectangle without the circle appearing inside the rectangle?
2. How can I get the rectangle/circle to show while I'm dragging the mouse. What I mean is how can the lines show until I release the mouse click?
3. Why doesn't it work drawing by free hand?

[image]

This is my testclass:

```
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Lab6 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    int startX, startY, endX, endY, w, h;
    ArrayList<Shape> shapeList =  new ArrayList<Shape>();
    Container cp = getContentPane();

    private JPanel topPanel;
    private JComboBox comboBox;    
    private final String[] boxOptions = new String[] {"Rektangel", "Cirkel", "Frihand"};   


    public Lab6(String title) {
        super(title);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);        
        this.setSize(840, 500);    
        this.initComponents();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }


    private void initComponents() {
        topPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));     
        topPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0,40));

        comboBox = new JComboBox(boxOptions);
        comboBox.setSelectedIndex(0);          
        comboBox.addActionListener(this);                          

        topPanel.add(comboBox);
        this.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);          
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        for (Shape s : shapeList) {
            s.draw(g);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource().equals(comboBox)) {     
            JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
            if (cb.getSelectedItem().equals("Rektangel")) {                
                cp.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {            
                    @Override
                    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {                   
                        startX = e.getX();     
                        startY = e.getY(); 
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                        endX = e.getX();
                        endY = e.getY();

                        int width = startX - endX;
                        int height = startY - endY;
                        w = Math.abs(width);
                        h = Math.abs(height);

                        Rectangle r =  new Rectangle(startX, startY, w, h);

                        shapeList.add(r);
                        repaint();
                    }
                });                  
            }
            else if (cb.getSelectedItem().equals("Cirkel")) {

                cp.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {            
                    @Override
                    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {                   
                        startX = e.getX();     
                        startY = e.getY(); 
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                        endX = e.getX();
                        endY = e.getY();

                        int width = startX - endX;
                        int height = startY - endY;
                        w = Math.abs(width);
                        h = Math.abs(height);

                        Circle c =  new Circle(startX, startY, w, h);

                        shapeList.add(c);
                        repaint();
                    }
                });   
            }
            else if (cb.getSelectedItem().equals("Frihand")) {   //I need help with this part

               cp.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {            
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {            
                    startX = e.getX();
                    startY = e.getY();
                }
                @Override
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

                    FreeHand fh =  new FreeHand(startX, startY, e.getX(), e.getY());

                    shapeList.add(fh);
                    repaint();
                }
            });  

            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Lab6("Drawing Program");
    }
}
```

In class Rectangle (class Circle looks the same):

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Rectangle extends Shape {

    public Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        super(x, y, width, height);
    }

    public Rectangle() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
        public void draw(Graphics g) {  
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;             
            g2.setColor(Color.RED);                     
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4));           
            g.drawRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());       
    }        
}
```

In class FreeHand (I need help with this part):

```
import java.awt.*;

public class FreeHand extends Shape {

    public FreeHand(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        super(x, y, width, height);
    }

    public FreeHand() {
        super();
    }        

    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;             
        g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);                    
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4));           
        g2.drawLine(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());  
    }
}
```

In class shape:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public abstract class Shape extends JPanel {

    private int startX, startY, width, height;    

    public Shape() {
        this(0, 0, 1, 1);
    }

    public Shape(int startX, int startY, int width, int height) {
        this.startX = startX;
        this.startY = startY;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public abstract void draw(Graphics g);

    @Override
    public int getX() {
        return startX;
    }

    @Override
    public int getY() {
        return startY;
    }

    @Override
    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    @Override
    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a multitude of things going on...

1. Overriding `paint` of `JFrame`
2. Not calling `super.paint` before performing custom painting.
3. Adding a new `MosueListener` EVERY time you change the shape

Instead, create a custom component, extending from something like `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method.  Use this component has your basic drawing surface (your controls should contained in another component).

Make sure you call `super.paintComponent` before performing any custom painting so you don't break the paint chain

See [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details

Create a SINGLE `MouseListener` and register it to the panel.  When the use selects a different shape, change a state variable within the panel (via a setter) which tells the `MouseListener` what it should do when the user starts drawing.

**Updated...**

Create a custom class that extends from `JPanel`...

```
public static class ShapePane extends JPanel {

}
```

Override the classes `paintComponent` method...

```
public static class ShapePane extends JPanel {

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        // Custom Painting here...
    }

}
```

Provide some sizing hints for the layout manager...

```
public static class ShapePane extends JPanel {

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        // Custom Painting here...
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }

}
```

Provide a means by which the type of shape can be changed...so you know what to paint...

```
public static class ShapePane extends JPanel {

    public enum ShapeType {

        CIRCLE,
        RECTANGLE
    }

    private ShapeType currentShapeType;

    public void setCurrentShapeType(ShapeType currentShapeType) {
        this.currentShapeType = currentShapeType;
    }

    public ShapeType getCurrentShapeType() {
        return currentShapeType;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        // Custom Painting here...
    }

}
```

Add a SINGLE `MouseListener` to the custom class to create the required type of shapes...

```
public static class ShapePane extends JPanel {

    public enum ShapeType {

        CIRCLE,
        RECTANGLE
    }

    private ShapeType currentShapeType;

    public ShapePane() {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            private Point clickPoint;

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                clickPoint = e.getPoint();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                Point releasePoint = e.getPoint();
                int x = Math.min(releasePoint.x, clickPoint.x);
                int y = Math.min(releasePoint.y, clickPoint.y);
                int width = Math.abs(clickPoint.x - releasePoint.x);
                int height = Math.abs(clickPoint.y - releasePoint.y);
                switch (getCurrentShapeType()) {
                    case CIRCLE:
                        // Make a circle
                        break;
                    case RECTANGLE:
                        // Make a rectangle...
                        break;
                }
                repaint();
            }

        });
    }

    public void setCurrentShapeType(ShapeType currentShapeType) {
        this.currentShapeType = currentShapeType;
    }

    public ShapeType getCurrentShapeType() {
        return currentShapeType;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        // Custom Painting here...
    }

}
```

Fill in the blanks...

Create another `JPanel` (you can simply create an instance this time), add your controls to it

Create an instance of a `JFrame`, add the custom class to it and the controls panel (make sure they are laid out correctly so they don't override each other - see [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details)

Use appropriate listeners to the controls to determine the type of shape the user wants to draw and set the `currentShapeType` property accordingly...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately I don't understand what  you mean.
1. Do  you mean I should NOT override paint? If I remove @Override nothing Changes, the problem remains.
2. Where exactly in the code should I remove the call to super.paint? 
3. Do you mean I should not add a new MouseListerner every time? How can I register the mouselistener to the panel? How till the code look like?

Also, i'm not sure I understand what you mean by creating a custom Component, extending JPanel and override paintcomponent?
Once again, thanks for your time. I appreciate it.

Comment: Start by reading the linked tutorials. Second, every time you select a shape type from the combobox, you are creating a new instance of a `MouseListener` add attaching it to your frame.  This means if I choose circle, rectangle, circle, there are now THREE mouse listeners, each which will be notified when a mouse event occurs...

Comment: Thank you for explaining about the mouselistener. It cleared things out. How would the code look like to create one single mouselistener, and where do I put it?
I will read the link, thanks again.

Comment: I'd add the listener in the constructor of the custom panel...

Comment: Ok, but how will the line of code for that look like in the constructor?

Comment: 1+ to Mad's answer. @user2939293: why not first try it out and see what you can come up, and see if it works?

Comment: It would look almost the same as it does when you create it within your listeners...