# Switch between drawing a rectangle and by freehand

Tags: java, swing, java-2d, custom-painting

I have some issues with my paint program in Java.

I have a `JComboBox` where I can choose to draw either a rectangle or by freehand. The objects are added to an `ArrayList`. I want to be able to switch between drawing a rectangle and by free hand, and then back to drawing a rectangle, and then by free hand... and so on.

If I do that as the code looks like now, it first draws rectangles fine and then when I switch to free hand it draws lines fine, but then when I switch back to rectangles it still draws lines (or sometimes lines together with weird looking rectangles). The more I switch the weirder it gets.

Can anyone see what is wrong with the code, because I can't?

```
public abstract class Draw  {
    public int startX, startY, endX, endY, width, height, w, h;
    public String color = "Black";


    public Draw(int startX, int startY, int width, int height) {
        this.startX = startX;
        this.startY = startY;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public abstract void draw(Graphics2D g);       

    public int getX() {
        return startX;
    }

    public void setX(int startX) {
        this.startX = startX;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return startY;
    }

    public void setY(int startY) {
        this.startY = startY;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(int width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}



public class Rectangle extends Draw {

    public Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        super(x, y, width, height);
    }        

    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics2D g2) {
        g2.drawRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
    }  
}

public class FreeHand extends Draw {

     public FreeHand(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        super(x, y, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics2D g2) {            
        g2.drawLine(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}

public class PaintProgram extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public ArrayList<Draw> shapeList = new ArrayList<>();   
    int startX, startY, endX, endY, w, h;
    private JPanel topPanel;   
    private JPanel bottomPanel;
    private JPanel leftPanel;
    private JPanel rightPanel;
    private JComboBox comboBox;
    private final String[] boxOptions = new String[] {"Rectangle", "Freehand"};   
    Container cp = getContentPane();
    private int count = 0;


    public JavaApplication30(String title) {
        super(title);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);        
        this.setSize(840, 500);     
        this.initComponents();
        this.setVisible(true);            
    }


    private void initComponents() {

        cp.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        comboBox = new JComboBox(boxOptions);
        topPanel = new JPanel();     
        bottomPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));  
        rightPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
        leftPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

        comboBox.setSelectedIndex(0);          
        comboBox.addActionListener(this); 

        topPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0,40));        
        bottomPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0,30));                       
        bottomPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);        

        topPanel.add(comboBox);
        bottomPanel.add(leftPanel);        
        bottomPanel.add(rightPanel);

        this.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);          
        this.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);                  
    }


    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        if(count == 0) {
            cp.repaint();
        }
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        for (Draw d : shapeList) {
            d.draw(g2);
        }        

        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));

        if (startX != 0 && startY != 0 && endX != 0 && endY != 0) {

            int width = Math.abs(startX - endX);
            int height = Math.abs(startY - endY);

            int minX = Math.min(startX, endX);
            int minY = Math.min(startY, endY);               

            Rectangle r = new Rectangle(minX, minY, width, height);

            g2.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
            g2.fillRect(r.getX(), r.getY(), r.getWidth(), r.getHeight()); 
            r.setColor(pickedColor);

            r.draw(g2);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        count++;

        if (e.getSource().equals(comboBox)) {    

            JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)e.getSource();

            if (cb.getSelectedItem().equals("Rectangle")) {

                this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {    

                    @Override
                    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {                   
                        startX = e.getX();     
                        startY = e.getY(); 

                        endX = startX;  
                        endY = startY;  
                        repaint(); 
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                        endX = e.getX();
                        endY = e.getY();

                        int width = Math.abs(startX - endX);
                        int height = Math.abs(startY - endY);

                        int minX = Math.min(startX, endX);
                        int minY = Math.min(startY, endY);               

                        Rectangle r =  new Rectangle(minX, minY, width, height);
                        shapeList.add(r);
                        r.setColor(pickedColor);

                        startX = 0;
                        startY = 0;
                        endX = 0;
                        endY = 0;
                        repaint();
                    }
                });    

                this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                        endX = e.getX();
                        endY = e.getY();
                        repaint();
                    }
                });
            }            


            else if (cb.getSelectedItem().equals("Freehand")) {

                this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {                   
                    @Override
                    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {                   
                        startX = e.getX();
                        startY = e.getY();                       
                        addCoordinate(startX, startY);
                    }
                });

                this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {                
                        Graphics g = getGraphics();    
                        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;         

                        FreeHand fh =  new FreeHand(startX, startY, e.getX(), e.getY());
                        shapeList.add(fh);
                        fh.setColor(pickedColor);
                        fh.draw(g2);                    
                        startX = e.getX();
                        startY = e.getY();                         
                    }
                });    
            }
        }
    }                 

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new PaintProgram("Paint");
    }
}
```

Comment: So, this is like the third time you, or this code, has been asked. Don't keep switching the mouse listeners. Keep a single mouse listener and manage the state based on the selected item...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add MouseListeners but you do not remove them. Every time you choose something in the combobox, a new listener is added. So when you draw something every listener is applied and weird stuff will happen.

You should remove the previous MouseListener before adding a new one. You might have to remember it in an instance variable.

Alternatively, you can add all listeners at the start, but check the value of the combobox inside the listener. If the value does not correspond to what the listener is for, it should do nothing.

EDIT: Here is how you can remove all listeners

```
    for (MouseListener listener : this.getMouseListeners()) {
        this.removeMouseListener(listener);
    }
    for (MouseMotionListener listener : this.getMouseMotionListeners()) {
        this.removeMouseMotionListener(listener);
    }
```

Put this code in before you add the new listeners in the actionPerformed() method

Comment: Ok, this is new to me. I didn't know I could remove a listener. How can I do that? And how do I remember it in an instance variable. Thank you for your time

Comment: *"I didn't know I could remove a listener. How can I do that?"* It would be better to add a single listener and never add more!

Comment: @AndrewThompson I agree to a point. This is somewhat of a "quick fix", which should work fine in this situation.

Comment: Based on the fact that this is third time the OP has asked the question and the second time that this "fix" has been suggest...I doubt providing a "quick fix" is the solution that either the OP needs or we want

Comment: @MadProgrammer I wasn't aware this question has been asked before. Perhaps it should just be marked as a duplicate then.

Comment: @David ten Hove  can you also help me with this question: Do I have to change this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter) to cp.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter)?

Comment: @user2939293 NO! Never add a `MouseListener` to a `JComboBox` (or `JButton` for that matter), they can be activated through the use of the keyboard OR mouse OR programmatically.

Comment: @DavidtenHove It probably should be, but I'm trying to drag the OP, apparently kicking and screaming, across the line to a stable and manageable solution, which not only helps them, but also other people who might try similarly, interesting, solutions...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I appreciate  you trying to help me.
cp is the contentpane. I think you mixed it up witd cb which is the combobox. (Perhaps bad naming of me). I was thinking maybe I should add the mouselistener to the contentpane instead of JFrame (this).

Comment: @user2939293 Yes, I  mixed it up, but still, no. MouseEvents are contextual, that is, they are translated in such away that the position 0x0 is the top/left corner of the component that generated the event. Since you shouldn't be painting directly onto a frame in the first place, I would argue that you shouldn't be add a MouseListener to either

Comment: @MadProgrammer So, you're saying I should change this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter) to contentPane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter)?

Comment: @user2939293 No, I'm saying you shouldn't add a MouseListener to the frame OR content pane. If you override paint of JFrame, you are painting to the frames surface, the content pane sits on top of the JRootPane, which sits on top of the JFrame.

Comment: @MadProgrammer thank you (again) for your help. You really know you java. Also, thank you David ten Hove, your solution solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

As was stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684750/java-only-addmouselistener-once) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26662768/how-to-get-rid-of-circle-inside-rectangle-when-switching-between-objects) previously, do not add `MouseListener`s within your `ActionListener`, instead, create a single `MosueListener` and determine what you want to do based on the currently selected item.

Basically, you keep adding a new `MouseListener` each time `actionPerformed` is called...they are accumulating...

A solution would be to use a single `MouseListener` and a factory of some kind...

Start by defining the factory interface...

```
public interface DrawFactory {

    public Draw createDrawing(int x, int y, int width, int height, Color color);
    public void addPoint(Draw draw, int x, int y);

}
```

Create a implementation of the factory for each type of shape you want to draw...

```
public class RectangleFactory implements DrawFactory {

    @Override
    public Draw createDrawing(int x, int y, int width, int height, Color color) {
        return new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void addPoint(Draw draw, int x, int y) {
        // Does nothing...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMutable() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Rectangle";
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getName();
    }

}

public class FreeHandFactory implements DrawFactory {

    @Override
    public Draw createDrawing(int x, int y, int width, int height, Color color) {
        return new FreeHand(x, y, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void addPoint(Draw draw, int x, int y) {
        if (draw instanceof FreeHand) {
            FreeHand fh = (FreeHand)draw;
            //fh.addPoint(x, y);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMutable() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Free Hand";
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getName();
    }

}
```

Next, create a custom component that extends from `JPanel` which will act as the primary drawing surface, this will be repsonsible for monitoring the `MouseLstener` and painting the `Draw` instances, as was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26723764/clear-window-from-drawing-objects)

```
public class DrawSurface extends JPanel {

    private DrawFactory factory;
    private Draw currentDraw;
    private List<Draw> shapeList = new ArrayList<>();
    private Color drawColor;

    public DrawSurface() {
        shapeList = new ArrayList<>(25);
        MouseAdapter ma = new MouseAdapter() {

            private Point pressPoint;

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                pressPoint = e.getPoint();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                DrawFactory factory = getDrawFactory();
                if (factory != null) {
                    Point p = e.getPoint();
                    if (factory.isMutable() && currentDraw != null) {
                        factory.addPoint(currentDraw, p.x, p.y);
                    } else {
                        int x = Math.min(p.x, pressPoint.x);
                        int y = Math.min(p.y, pressPoint.y);

                        int width = Math.abs(p.x - pressPoint.x);
                        int height = Math.abs(p.y - pressPoint.y);

                        Draw draw = factory.createDrawing(x, y, width, height, getDrawColor());
                        shapeList.add(draw);
                        if (factory.isMutable()) {
                            currentDraw = draw;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public DrawFactory getDrawFactory() {
        return factory;
    }

    public void setDrawFactory(DrawFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
        currentDraw = null;
    }

    public Color getDrawColor() {
        return drawColor;
    }

    public void setDrawColor(Color drawColor) {
        this.drawColor = drawColor;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        for (Draw draw : shapeList) {
            draw.draw(g2d);
        }
        g2d.dispose();
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }

}
```

Next, change your `boxOptions` from `String` to `DrawFactory`, this will make it easier to determine which factory you should use.  Don't forget to add a reference to the `DrawSurface`

```
private final DrawFactory[] boxOptions = new DrawFactory[]{new RectangleFactory(), new FreeHandFactory()};
private DrawSurface drawSurface;
```

In your `initComponents` create a new instance of `DrawSurface` and add it to your frame...

```
private void initComponents() {
    //...    
    drawSurface = new DrawSurface();
    this.add(drawSurface);
}
```

Change your `actionPerformed` method to look more like...

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    count++;
    drawSurface.setDrawFactory((DrawFactory)comboBox.getSelectedItem());
}
```

Not sure how you are determining the current color as you example code is incomplete, but basically, you want to set the `drawColor` of the `DrawSurface` similarly.

Get rid of the `paint` method in the `PaintProgram` as you shouldn't be overriding the `paint` method of top level containers, which you've been advised against at least once, if not twice.

The point of all this is simple, when you want to add a new "drawing shape", you create a `Draw` and `DrawFactory` for it and add the factory to the combo box ... work done...

Comment: Thank you , but this solotion is a bit too complicated for me. I'll go with David ten Hove's solution above.

Comment: Well, you have a choice, either to learn how to it well, or forever be trying to fix one hack after another - just saying